# SQL Query for pull value in between index range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table in which i require Service Type field from 2nd table.

```
KmReading   ServiceType
40203   
30143   
30143   
30143
```

In table 2 i have index range for KMReading like

```
StartKM EndKM   ServiceType
0   2000    Service1
2001    7000    Service2
7001    12000   Service3
12001   17000   Service4
17001   22000   Service5
22001   27000   Service6
27001   32000   Service7
32001   37000   Service8
37001   42000   Service9
```

so if any value comes in between StartKM and EndKM in table1 then it can pull value of ServiceType from table2 to table1

Comment: Why is this tagged MySql but has MS Access in the title? Please clarify your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it maybe works for MS Access.

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.ServiceType = T2.ServiceType
FROM table1 T1
 JOIN table2 T2
   ON T1.KmReading BETWEEN T2.StartKM AND T2.EndKM
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: For MySQL this should do it:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2
SET t1.ServiceType = t2.ServiceType
WHERE t1.KmReading >= t2.StartKm AND t1.KmReading <= t2.EndKm
```